# Count occurences of values in a list with a twist

Tags: python

```
from random import randrange

ls = list(randrange(1,3) for x in range(10))
```

Output:`ls = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]`

What i want:
`{1:4,2:10}`

So i want that if a value `x` goes into the Counter, all counter values that are equal or smaller than the `x` should be increased by 1.
Is there a simple solution to this? Does `collections.Counter` have a parameter to solve this or is there a different short and elegant solution?

Comment: No, `collections.Counter` doesn't work that way. You'll have to put something together yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a dict-comprehension is short and elegant enough:

```
from random import randrange, seed

seed(42)
ls = list(randrange(1,3) for x in range(10))

print(ls)
# [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
dict_out = {
    element: sum([item <= element for item in ls])
    for element in set(ls)
}
print(dict_out)
# {1: 8, 2: 10}
```

Comment: Oh yes, that is exactly what i was hoping for. Thank you very much!

Comment: This solution is elegantly written, but worth noting that it runs in O(n^2) time.

Comment: Indeed, i just compared the execution time to the solution of Ajax1234 and indeed, his solution is way faster. However i need to do this only for n = 200. The problem indeed was that i was looking for a fast solution as well and i could not think of one...

Comment: Ajax1234's solution is also O(n^2), for the record.

Comment: It also uses a lot of space, since r is quite large. So would there be a faster solution than O(n^2) for this as well?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think @Durtal's answer is more elegant than mine, but I thought it would be worth adding a solution which runs in O(n log n) time, rather than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import accumulate

def count_less_or_equal(ls):
    keys, frequencies = zip(*sorted(Counter(ls).items()))
    return dict(zip(keys, accumulate(frequencies)))
```

O(n log n) is asymptotically optimal, because the problem is equivalent to sorting; given a list of distinct elements, each key in the output dictionary will be associated with its correct index in a sorted version of the original list, using 1-based indexing.

Based on the above observation, here is a smug solution which *might* be considered more elegant - it is a one-liner requiring no imports - but it relies on the fact that repeated keys in a dict comprehension are allowed, and keep their last value, which is arguably not elegant.

```py
def count_by_sorting(ls):
    return {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(ls), start=1)}
```

This code works, but it is a puzzler; somebody reading this code would have to think carefully about how it works and why it is correct. Compare with @Durtal's solution, which directly computes what it's supposed to in a fairly clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
r = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(ls))]
result = {a:len(b) + sum(len(y) for x, y in r if x < a) for a, b in r}
```

Output:

```
{1: 4, 2: 10}
```